# Karma.js not liking JavaScript var's inside of an Angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I've got some javascript var's in an Angular controller. Karma doesn't seem to like them. When I keep the var's inside of my controller, and run Karma, I get "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" errors. When I remove the var's - Karma works just fine. Any suggestions? Are var's inside of an Angular controller a big no-no? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's got nothing to do with var, I suspect your likes look like `var something = $('...')`. It doesn't know what `$` is.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing jQuery.  Make sure you include it in your [config file](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v0.8.5/test/client/karma.conf.js).

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  '../path/to/jquery.js',  
  // ...    
  'test/*.js'
];
```